# Remove rows that contain pipe ( | ) symbol

Tags: r

I have to remove rows that contain the pipe symbol.

My Input:

```
 > gene_anotation   

    probeset_id GeneSymbol Ensembl_gene_id
    17406395            Arfip1            <NA>
    17393207 LOC101056658|Ahcy            <NA>
    17467690             Ptcd3            <NA>
    17400375              Ctss            <NA>
```

My Expected output:

```
 > gene_anotation   

    probeset_id GeneSymbol Ensembl_gene_id
    17406395            Arfip1            <NA>
    17467690             Ptcd3            <NA>
    17400375              Ctss            <NA>
```

I already tried these, but with no results:

```
gene_anotation[!grepl("|", gene_anotation$GeneSymbol),]
```

or

```
gene_anotation[!gene_anotation$GeneSymbol == "|", ]
```

Comment: Have you tried to escape the `|` within `grepl`? Try `grepl("\|", gene_anotation$GeneSymbol)`

Comment: or rather `grepl("\\|", gene_anotation$GeneSymbol)`

Comment: Oops, one backslash got lost.

Comment: Yes, the double escape worked! thank you @Roland

Comment: or better yet, use `fixed = TRUE`, i.e. `grepl("|", gene_anotation$GeneSymbol, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: stringr + tidyverse approach: `gene_anotation %>% filter(!str_detect(pattern='\\|', string=GeneSymbol))`